# Can a person use a picture of me for a non profit organization? It’s on the internet and I’m not happy about it?

Tags: internet

My picture is on a non profit organization without my permission. Can this be removed ? The title at hand states recovering sexual abuse .

Comment: What jurisdiction are you in? What country? If a federal country6 such as the US, Canada, or India, what state or province? Laws vary on such matters.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in the US, t6hat youa re recovering from sexual abuse might constitute Protected Health Information PHI) under HIPAA (the US Federal Health Insurance .Portability and Accessibility Act). That generally prohibits disclosure of PHI without permission except in certain limited cases, bu8t it only applies to providers of health care, Insurance companies, and people and entities who obtain information from such covered entities. So it would matter how this non-profit got your info.

If they are using your image to promote their services, in some US states that might violate your personality rights, your right to sell your endorsement. Not all states recognize such rights. You might need to show some likelihood that you could sell your endorsement for a meaningful sum.

In some US states this might violate your privacy rights by begin a disclosure of Private Facts. Not all US states recognize this tort, and your would have to establish damages, for which "I don't like it" would not be enough.

If the statement that you are a victim of sexual abuse  is false, it might be defamatory, but you would need to show significant damage to yo0ur reputation. Such a suit would be expensive, and the amount of a damage award uncertain even if you won.

You might do well to simply contact the non-profit and request that the image be taken down. It is not unlikely that it would comply, even if you do not have the legal right to force them to do so or to sue for damages. If that does not work, you might want to consult a lawyer who has knowledge of this area and of your local laws.

Comment: Personally, I would hire a lawyer to draft the cease and desist.  Even if you don't have legal recourse, having the attorney's letterhead might be enough to get them to take it down